# bash color settings messing something up

Tags: bash, ps1

```
blue="\033[38;5;32m\]\033[48;5;256m\]"
purple="\033[38;5;198m\]"
green="\[\033[0;32m\]"
reset="\[\033[0m\]"

export PS1="$purple\u$green\$(__git_ps1)$blue \W $ $reset"
```

If the colors were set using the simpler format, as for `green`, everything would work fine. But if they're set using the more complex format like in `blue` and `purple`, it would work and look right at first, but if I navigate through some previous commands etc. suddenly the line would jump into a really weird place and the prompt text would be gone.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you surround the escape codes with `\[` and `\]`. Those markers tell bash that these are non-printing characters.

```
blue="\[\033[38;5;32m\033[48;5;256m\]"
purple="\[\033[38;5;198m\]"
```